# Remove character after '-' from string and group that remaining string together

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, group-by, pivot

Here is my actual data in Excel, which I am successfully able to read in DataGridView in C# Windows Application.

```
Test       | Energy |
---------------------
C018-3L-1  | 113    |
C018-3L-2  | 79     |
C018-3L-3  | 89     |
C021-3T-1  | 115    |
C021-3T-2  | 100    |
```

But now I want this data in DataGridView in below Format:

```
Test    |Energy-1|Energy-2|Energy-3 |
------------------------------------
C018-3L |113     |79      |89       |
C021-3T |115     |100     |NULL     |
```

Here is my code:

```
    private void TensileEnergyData_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string sourcefilepath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString();

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcefilepath, "*.xlsx");
            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                string excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + s + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES';";

                // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select Test, Energy FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
                    da.Fill(dtExcelData);
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            objDAL.SendExcepToDB(ex, "TensileEnergyData_Load");
            MessageBox.Show("Fail to read data...!!");
        }
        dataGridView1.Visible = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtExcelData;
    }
```

How can I achieve this using Group By?

Comment: What attempts have you made so far?

Comment: is there n number energy or 1 to 3 fixed ?

Comment: @AGH I updated the question will you please refer it..

Comment: @Larnu I am able to read all the data from excel file in my data grid view but the problem is i want to read the data in grid view as given format from the same excel file.

Comment: Initially you tagged to SQL and got responses, instead of updating the question for different requirements, you should have created another question to get better response.

Comment: Hi dmegha, you are new here, so no offence, but: This is a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/311071) now and this is seen as a *no no* here on SO. Why? Your changes **invalidate existing answers**, future visitors will read answers not fitting to the question (*Whaaat?*) and you switch around with the acceptance check, as if this was kind of a goody to attract foreign strangers to solve your problem... So please: Rollback your changes, accept the answer which you like best in the point of view of the initial issue and start a new question with more details (-> [mcve])

Comment: @Shnugo I rollback my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is marked with `[sql-server]`. This is a SQL-Server approach:

You can try this

I create a *mockup table*

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Test VARCHAR(100),Energy INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('C018-3L-1',113)
,('C018-3L-2',79)
,('C018-3L-3',89)
,('C021-3T-1',115)
,('C021-3T-2',100);
```

This is the query

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT LEFT(t.Test,7) AS Test
          ,CONCAT('Energy-',RIGHT(t.Test,1)) AS ColumnName
          ,Energy
    FROM @tbl t
) tbl
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Energy) FOR ColumnName IN([Energy-1],[Energy-2],[Energy-3])
) p;
```

The result

```
Test        Energy-1    Energy-2    Energy-3
C018-3L     113         79          89
C021-3T     115         100         NULL
```

Some explanation:

This is relying on a fix format of your string and a maximum of 3 columns. Another approach was to search for the last hyphen and use its position to split the string in the leading part and the number. With a varying count of numbers you must either know the expected maximum or you must walk a generic route entirely (e.g. dynamic SQL).

Comment: sir but there are some changes in my requirement so will you please refer the question again..and help me.. Thank you again. :)

Comment: @dmegha Okay, you placed a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54801595/5089204). That's good, I've answered there already. Next time please place a link to your new question here in the comments. this will give us an alert, that there is a *follow-up* question. And please do not forget to rollback your changes and to accept the answer you like most. Help us to keep SO tidy and clean...

Comment: Yes sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach can be using `CASE`

```
SELECT t.Test, 
       Max(energy1) [Energy-1], 
       Max(energy2) [Energy-2], 
       Max(energy3) [Energy-3] 
FROM   (SELECT LEFT(test, Len(test) - Charindex('-', Reverse(test))) Test, 
              case  when test like '%-1' then Energy  else null end 'Energy1',
              case  when test like '%-2' then Energy  else null end 'Energy2',
              case  when test like '%-3' then Energy  else null end 'Energy3'
        FROM   [TABLE_NAME]) t 
GROUP  BY t.test
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/QQR51618)

Comment: Thank you so much..it works perfectly.. but there is some changes in my requirement so will please refer the question again..and help me.. Thank you very much for the demo explanation.

Comment: Do you mean the UI part?

Comment: In my excel sheet...there is a continue data like 1,2,3,4.. so on but i want it in a group of 3 in data grid view as i shown in question

Comment: I can suggest if you can raise a new question for .net, you will get better response, tag all applicable technologies. By changing existing question in validates all the answers.